# 100% height div in angularjs (ng-scope class issue)

Tags: css, angularjs, height

I want to put a 100% height image in my front page that fills the whole screen, and then show other images and text when scrolling. I followed this guide to do so:

Demo: http://www.minimit.com/demos/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content

Explanation: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content

The issue is that, as far as I am concerned, if you want to have a div that is 100% the height of the browser window, you need to give 100% height to all its parent elements. Therefore, in order to make this work in angularjs I have given 100% height to html, body and ng-scope (using min-height:100% does not work).

The problem is that having height:100% in the ng-scope class leads to some unwanted behavior. For example, if I want to add a footer (which is static, outside the ng-view directive), the footer is displayed right after the first 100% height, instead of appearing at the end of the page, something like what I simulated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3zbufhk/

by simulating the ng-scope class with:

```
#ng-scope {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

So, is there any way of having 100% height divs in angularjs without modifying the height of ng-scope?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: By 100% height div, I mean a div that is 100% height of the browser window.

Comment: 100% height = 100% document height?

Comment: Yes, sorry because it is probably unclear. I want a div that is 100% the height of the browser. Thank you!

Comment: The minimit website isn't loading for me.  Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x3zbufhk/1/)?  On a side note, using `#ng-scope` is the ID `ng-scope` not the class.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. I want this behavior for long content inside the .ng-scope class: http://jsfiddle.net/getg811q and this behavior for short content: http://jsfiddle.net/hcpr96ar . But I don't know how to accomplish this, since for the short content you need html, body and ng-scope to have height:100%, while for the long content the footer is wrongly placed with that configuration: http://jsfiddle.net/x3zbufhk

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I'm facing the exact same problem

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit hacky, and doesn't entirely answer your question (how to do this without modifying ng-scope), but it does work.

```
html, body, .ng-scope {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or with Bootstrap

```
html, body, .ng-scope, .container-fluid, .row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` on `#ng-scope` **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8yxcvvy/)**

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. For some reason using min-height in .ng-scope does not work to make the image 100% size of the window (following the tutorial that I linked), but you are totally right it works with the text that I used to simulate the issue in fiddle. Let me try to figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed this problem while using Wijmo FlexGrid and AlgularJS.

I'm trying to edit a multi-line textarea within the celltemplate of my grid.  When I get into edit mode then wijmo inserts a div around my textarea with a class of ng-scope.  As you noticed changing the .ng-scope { height: 100% } royally screws with your whole page.  If you use the F12 / Developer tools in your browser you can inspect the elements around the attribute you are trying to resize.  In my case it looked like this:

[image: devtoolsimage]

the offending div was **ng-scope** which had a height of 144px.

I added to my site.css an override based on the nested class .wj-cell .ng-scope

[image]

This will only modify ng-scope when its parent has a class of wj-cell.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of using**

```
{
height : 100%
}
```

**try this instead**

```
{
height: 100vh;
}
```